# Mac Mini 2018 (Intel) has CPU frequency being 0.8GHz from time to time - what should I do?

Tags: mac-mini, cpu, temperature

I have a Mac Mini 2018 with Intel CPU, but recently it starts to lock its CPU frequency. From time to time (e.g. several times a day), it becomes 0.8GHz for about 5 minute, and a few minutes of ~1GHz, and then go back to normal 3-4 GHz.

I suspect this is because of overheating. However, the room temperature is not high - less than 30 degree Celsius. Another guess is there may be dust inside the fan so the fan does not work well? Or, is it possible that CPU silicone grease does not work well?

So what should I do? Shall I go to offline apple stores and ask them to check this? Will they handle such cases or not? Will it be expensive? I have bought AC+, and this machine is bought about 2.5 years ago, so I can use AC+ if needed.

Comment: Is this seemingly slowing down your work, or are you just seeing the frequency number somewhere?

Comment: @Undo I cannot do anything during the 0.8GHz time - just sit and wait :( Because I am a programmer and you know, programming (compiling, using IDE, etc) requires lots of CPU, and 0.8GHz makes those software almost freezed.

Comment: Did you open the Mini (turn it off, turn it around, rotate the bottom plate a bit) to check for dust?

Comment: @nohillside I have turned it around and look at it, and cannot rotate the bottom plate (seems non-rotatable). A bit of dust there, but if there is dust it can be inside instead of being there.

Comment: Ah, right, that only worked in older models. See https://www.wikihow.com/Open-a-Mac-Mini for how to open a 2018 model.

Comment: @nohillside Will I lose my AC+ if I open it?

Comment: If you have AC+, why not take it to the store?

Comment: Yes. If you're paying for AppleCare, then you should use it. The 2018 Minis are prone to fluff build-up.

Comment: @nohillside Sure, I will do that. I was just wondering whether they will fix it or not since this is not something like "computer cannot boot"